# How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to surround a number in a circle like in this image:

[image: Number in Circle Image]

Is this possible and how is it achieved?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

Here's a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/k8gspoyv/) and a snippet:

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;

    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;

    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle">30</div>
```

My answer is a good starting point, some of the other answers provide flexibility for different situations. If you care about IE8, look at the [old version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4861306/3) of my answer.

Comment: The current latest version of Internet Explorer, 9, actually supports border-radius.  ...and div isn't a great choice for this. :)

Comment: To make it work in fiddle, you could go against a CDN, like [jsdelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!css3pie), instead of using a relative path for the URL.  If you update the URL in your fiddle with `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/css3pie/2.0b1/PIE.htc` it should work everywhere without additional retooling.

Comment: @KyleMit: That's a good idea, in theory. Unfortunately, CSS3 PIE has a [same-domain limitation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#x-domain).

Comment: Also, if you have a global line-height set to 1.5, you have to set it to 1 for this to work...

Comment: Width and Height is the key. I just used padding but then there was the 10. Thanks

Comment: To avoid having to do math in the CSS whenever you change the font-size (a hassle if you are doing responsive design for example), you can use this adaption of thirtydot's jsfiddle that only uses pixels to describe the font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/dQR9T/7058/

Comment: @Steven The **last edit** on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359039/607874) (titled as "Resize with content") works for any font size and any content length.

Comment: @Steven: You can also do things like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/dQR9T/7066/

Comment: This only works for the width / height / border-width in the sample. As soon as these values are changed it looks really bad. As @jeffaudio points out, the style needs `box-sizing: content-box` to work correctly.

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler: Look at my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-use-css-to-surround-a-number-with-a-circle/4861306#comment66101518_4861306). You are free to downvote, but the other 241 upvoters thought this answer was at least a useful starting point...

Comment: @steven how to ensure **the circle is always around the number** , or can we make the circle bigger if the number is 24928 _it overflows right now_

Comment: @transformer: The circle would have to be almost 3x its current size, which may be fine for your design. You could instead reduce the font size or format the number as 24.9k instead (from a design point of view, and likely will require JavaScript).

Comment: Removed padding to get the number inside the circle

Comment: What about setting 'line-height' instead of padding?

Comment: Is there a way to the other way round. I have an object which is round. I want to place a number obove it.

Comment: in 2022 --- yuk

Answer (score 152):

The problem with most of the other answers here is you need to tweak the size of the outer container so that it is the perfect size based on the font size and number of characters to be displayed. If you are mixing 1 digit numbers and 4 digit numbers, it won't work. If the ratio between the font size and the circle size isn't perfect, you'll either end up with an oval or a small number vertically aligned at the top of a large circle. This should work fine for any amount of text and any size circle. Just set the `width` and `line-height` to the same value:

```css
.numberCircle {
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle">1</div>
<div class="numberCircle">100</div>
<div class="numberCircle">10000</div>
<div class="numberCircle">1000000</div>
```

If you need to make the content longer or shorter, all you need to do is adjust the width of the container for a better fit.

[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89pd04ot/326/).

Comment: That's exactly the problem I was having, showing a percentage inside that could be '1', '10' or '100'. This works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Note [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9495706) was denied, but the changes actually center the text a bit better vertically, so I've added them to the answer manually.

Comment: This is the better answer. I would use translateY(-50%) instead of the negative top margin

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for the great idea. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It would be much cleaner to remove the span and add the `text-align` and `line-height` to the div. Still the best answer probably.

Comment: @dlsso Very true. I've updated the answer based on your observation. The reason I had it like that was because it's gone through so many versions that are significantly different from each other ([see revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19613616/revisions)), but I was mostly concerned about updating the CSS, not the HTML.

Answer (score 64):

For circle sizes varying based on the content this should work:

```css
.numberCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.numberCircle span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<span class="numberCircle"><span>30</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>1</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>5435</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>2</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle"><span>100</span></span>
```

It relies on the width of the content plus the `margin-`'s to determine the radius, then extends the height to match using the `padding-`'s. The `margin-`'s would need to be adjusted based on the font-size.

**Update to remove inner element:**

```css
.numberCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.numberCircle:before,
.numberCircle:after {
  content: '\200B';
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.numberCircle:before {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.numberCircle:after {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<span class="numberCircle">30</span>
<span class="numberCircle">1</span>
<span class="numberCircle">5435</span>
<span class="numberCircle">2</span>
<span class="numberCircle">100</span>
```

Uses pseudo-elements to force the height. Need the zero width space for vertical alignment. Moved the `line-height:0px` from the outer to the pseudo so that it is at least visible when degrading for IE8.

Comment: For me, this was the best solution. It allows larger numbers, and is the most scalable. All the other solutions have way too much hard coding of sizes. This has the least. Font-size can be changed a fair amount without breaking this. If changed drastically, the margin needs to be adjusted, but it is very forgiving. Having to use a nested element is somewhat of a negative though.

Comment: @Necreaux Updated the answer with a version that replaces the explicit inner element with pseudo-elements.

Comment: Best solution indeed. I just replaced the margin-left and margin-right size by 0.35em instead of 8px (padding in updated solution). So that you can change the number font-size and keep a suited margin.

Comment: The best one it woked well with all sizes

Comment: This was the best answer, but now that flexbox exists, I think this better, no pseudo-elements, nice and short: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65314495/1028679

Answer (score 58):

If it's 20 and lower, you can just use the unicode characters ① ② ... ⑳

http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/enclosed_alphanumerics.html

Comment: A nice idea but beware you are breaking semantics if the circle is for display purposes only

Answer (score 32):

the easiest way is using bootstrap and badge class

```
 <span class="badge">1</span>
```

Comment: bootstrap 5.2 introduced support for [badge background colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/badge/#background-colors)

Answer (score 30):

This version does not rely on hard-coded, fixed values but sizes relative to the `font-size` of the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/qod1vstv/

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.numberCircle {
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;

    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    box-sizing: initial;

    background: #fff;
    border: 0.1em solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;    

    line-height: 2em;
    box-sizing: content-box;   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="numberCircle">30</div>
<div class="numberCircle" style="font-size: 60px">1</div>
<div class="numberCircle" style="font-size: 12px">2</div>
```

Comment: hi this is very nice, but if the number is large, even in 100's or 1000's it scrolls out of the circle. Also, would it be possible to use the size of the font to create a new background color

Answer (score 10):

You can use the border-radius for this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .round
    {
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

  </style>
  </head>  
  <body>   
    <span class="round">30</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Play with the border radius and the padding values until you are satisfied with the result.

But this won't work in all browsers. I guess IE still does not support rounded corners.

Comment: dont forget ` -webkit-border-radius: 15px;` also there is a fix for IE http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser but think twice about implementing it

Comment: +1 probably the easiest method...fallback for IE looks ok as well (square). wordpress does it like this if i recall

Answer (score 9):

I am surprised nobody used `flex` which is easier to understand, so I put my version of answer here:

1. To create a circle, make sure `width` equals `height`
2. To adapt to `font-size` of number in the circle, use `em` rather than `px`
3. To center the number in the circle, use flex with `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`
4. if the number grows (>1000 for example), increase the `width` and `height` at same time

Here is an example:

```css
.circled-number {
  color: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 2em; 
  height: 2em;
}

.circled-number--big {
  color: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="circled-number">
  30
</div>

<div class="circled-number--big">
  3000000
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but here is a bootstrap-only solution that has worked for me. I'm using Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
<div class="row mt-4">
<div class="col-md-12">
<span class="bg-dark text-white rounded-circle px-3 py-1 mx-2 h3">1</span>
<span class="bg-dark text-white rounded-circle px-3 py-1 mx-2 h3">2</span>
<span class="bg-dark text-white rounded-circle px-3 py-1 mx-2 h3">3</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

You basically add `bg-dark text-white rounded-circle px-3 py-1 mx-2 h3` classes to your `<span>` (or whatever) element and you're done.

Note that you might need to adjust margin and padding classes if your content has more than one digits.

Answer (score 4):

My solution here - this easily allows for different sizes and colors and ties into a CMS for editorial control.  For IE degrading to squares.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="circular-label label-outer label-size-large label-color-pink">
    <div class="label-inner"> 
        <span>Fashion & Beauty</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.circular-label {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.label-inner {
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px dotted white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.label-inner > span {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 38%;
    font-family:'ProximaNovaLtSemibold';
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
}
.circular-label.label-size-large {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    -moz-border-radius: 55px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 55px;
    border-radius: 55px;
    margin-top:-55px;
}
.circular-label.label-size-med {
    width: 76px;
    height: 76px;
    -moz-border-radius: 38px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 38px;
    border-radius: 38px;
    margin-top:-38px;
}
.circular-label.label-size-med .label-inner > span {
    margin-top: 33%;
}
.circular-label.label-size-small {
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    -moz-border-radius: 33px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 33px;
    border-radius: 33px;
    margin-top:-33px;
}
```

It's not too difficult to see how to do this. The bigger question is whether it is possible to make the dimensions of the circle scale to content.

Currently I don't think it is possible. Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here's a [demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/El_Mehdi/qowvxmsf/15/) and a snippet:

```js
/* Creating a number within a circle using CSS */
```

```css
.numberCircle {
    font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold", Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 38px;
    min-height: 38px;
}

.numberCircle span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/* Some Back Ground Colors */
.clrGreen {
    background: #51a529;
}
.clrRose {
    background: #e6568b;
}
.clrOrange {
    background: #ec8234;
}
.clrBlueciel {
    background: #21adfc;
}
.clrMauve {
    background: #7b5d99;
}
```

```html
<span class="numberCircle clrGreen"><span>8</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle clrRose"><span>80</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle clrOrange"><span>800</span></span>
<span class="numberCircle clrMauve"><span>8000</span></span>
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the first one, because the circles stay at the same size, no matter what number is in them.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3><span class="numberCircle">1</span> Regiones del Interior</h3>
```

Comment: While this code is useful, it would be good to provide some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in your css

```
 div {
    width: 10em; height: 10em; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5em; -moz-border-radius: 5em;
  }
  p {
    text-align: center; margin-top: 4.5em;
  }
```

Use the paragraph tag to write the text. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work (for numbers 0 to 99):

```css
.circle {
  border: 0.1em solid grey;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle p {
  margin-top: 0.10em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <p>30</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving the first answer just get rid of the padding and add `line-height` and `vertical-align`:

```
.numberCircle {
   border-radius: 50%;       

   width: 36px;
   height: 36px;
   line-height: 36px;
   vertical-align:middle;

   background: #fff;
   border: 2px solid #666;
   color: #666;

   text-align: center;
   font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of thirtydot is right but is missing a little point. You need to add **position: relative** , if you want to have centered value in the circle and include also different range of number. 
For example 123;

HTML:

> `<div class="numberCircle">30</div>`

CSS:

```
.numberCircle {    

border-radius: 50%;
behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
padding: 8px;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #666;
color: #666;
text-align: center;

font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

but an easiest solution is to use Bootstrap

`<span class="badge" style ="float:right">123</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Heres my way of doing it, using square method. upside is it works with different values, but you need 2 spans.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.num {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.width_holder {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span class="width_holder">1</span>
  <span class="num">1</span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <span class="width_holder">11</span>
  <span class="num">11</span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <span class="width_holder">11111</span>
  <span class="num">11111</span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <span class="width_holder">11111111</span>
  <span class="num">11111111</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here's the solution I went with https://codepen.io/jnbruno/pen/vNpPpW

Required no extra work.
Thanks John Noel Bruno

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <h4>Normal Circle Buttons</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Who is John Noel Bruno? If get it from a blog or tutorial, providing links would be a plus

Comment: That requires bootstrap and fontawesome. You can see the in the Settings > CSS > External Stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```css
span.red {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.6em;
}

span.grey {
    background: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.6em;
}

span.green {
    background: #5EA226;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.6em;
}

span.blue {
    background: #5178D0;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.6em;
}

span.pink {
    background: #EF0BD8;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
    <h1><span class="grey">1</span>A grey circle with number inside</h1>
    <h1><span class="red">2</span>A red circle with number inside</h1>
    <h1><span class="blue">3</span>A blue circle with number inside</h1>
    <h1><span class="green">4</span>A green circle with number inside</h1>
    <h1><span class="pink">5</span>A pink circle with number inside</h1>
```

Thank to https://wpsites.net/web-design/colored-numbered-circles-using-pure-css-html/

Answer (score -1):

You work like with a standard block, that is a square

This is feature of CSS 3 and it is not very well suporrted, you can count on firefox and safari for sure.

```css
.circle {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span>1234</span></div>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work well