# Bit of css help please ( ol li stuff )

Tags: css

So I am doing a custom ol li list, and i really get confused with shortcuts css wise for ol , ul and li stuff.

If i tell you what I want, and provide some sample code could someone help please.

Ok so I am after a numbered list like so...

```
<ol>
    <li>Dave Jones<span class="searchTotals">189 searches</span></li>
    <li>Debs<span class="searchTotals">34 searches</span></li>
    <li>Tarbutt<span class="searchTotals">211 searches</span></li>
</ol>
```

What I want to do is NOT repeat the span class within the li element, so perhaps you could help.

Also I wanted to number style each li.

In so far as put a circle around each number..

Here is some css for the numbers.

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ec008c;
border-radius: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1em;
margin-left: 0.5em;
padding: 0.35em 0.5em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
```

Here is some css for the SPAN class.

```
float:right;
color:#3399ff;
```

Trying to get it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7? IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to float all the text in the div left without using span tags you can use this: (can't select just part of the text with `CSS`)

```
ol li {
   float:left;
   color:#3399ff;
}
```

If you want to have numbers with circles around them with the `li`, you're going to have to use images and use the `background:url()` property.

Comment: Why would I have to use images?

Comment: `CSS` currently does not provide a list-style with circles around numbers; maybe later on in `CSS3`, but not now.

Comment: Yes you have, but with images and not `list-style-type:` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_ol_list-style-type&preval=armenian

Comment: @422: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732836/html-css-numbered-list-with-numbers-inside-of-circles/5742176#5742176) will work in all modern browsers (including those you listed). In IE8, it will work but the corners won't be rounded. In IE7, there will be no numbers.

Comment: Voted your answer Phil, as only fair :) plus  tidies my CP up :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `background` for `li` elements