# How can i style a ol decimal?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to be able to add a purple circle background and change the color of just the number in an `ol li` decimal html element.

Is that possible without any extra markup? I've tried backgrounds, list-style-image etc etc, but none seem to so that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle showing exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something **[like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732836/html-css-numbered-list-with-numbers-inside-of-circles)** ?

Comment: @Kamo Correct me if I'm wrong, but if they could **make a JSFiddle showing exactly what they want to achieve** then they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @F4r-20 - true, but clarifying problem by creating fiddle, which simulates problem or shows it at least wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Kamo I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use another `span` element to format the background of each `li` numer. You can view the demo here [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/abamat/3/edit)

Comment: Based on your example, I've shortened the code by using the `:before` pseudo element - you can **[view it here](http://jsbin.com/abamat/5/edit)**. Sadly, this doesn't answer the question from John, since he doesn't want any extra markup.

Comment: I think i'm going to go with adding the span as it would give the most cross compatibility. I know i said i didn't want more markup, but looking at this, i don't think i have a choice. Thanks for the answers guys!!