# How to prepend a number before an HTML H2 with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a nice looking `H2` heading in HTML and CSS that will allow me to have a nice formatted Number before the actual Heading text, as shown in the following image:

[image]

The example in the image is using a CSS code like this below and it works great, except that I cannot set the number value in the orange circle in the HTML!

```css
h2:before {
  content: "2";
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #F77621;
}
```

```html
<h2>How to Get Detailed PPC Keyword Data</h2>
```

My other attempt is to Wrap the `h2` and a `span` both inside a `div`.  The span is holding the number circle:

```css
.number-circles {
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.number-circles h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  color: #555;
}
.number-circles span.num {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #F77621;
}
/* added to show the issue */
.number-circles {
  max-width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-circles">
  <span class="num">2</span>
  <h2>How to Get Detailed PPC Keyword Data</h2>
</div>
```

With this approach, I can set the value for the Number in the HTML.  The problem I have is when the `h2` text is too wide for a single line, then it makes the whole thing go to a new line and does not remain on the line with the circle number span.  This is bad! See image:

[image]

---

Can someone help me with a good solution that behave like the first one, where a wide h2 text will stay next to my number span?

Comment: Tip: just use `border-radius`. There’s no need to add `-webkit-` or `-moz-` anymore, and `-o-border-radius` and `-ms-border-radius` have never existed.

Comment: Use your first solution, and set the number from the CSS property using jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ... it works great, except that I cannot set the number value in the
>   orange circle in the HTML!

You can use [CSS pseudo elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) and HTML5 data attributes:

```css
h2:before {
  content: attr(data-number);
  display: inline-block;
  /* customize below */
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  width: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #F77621;
}
```

```html
<h2 data-number="2">Heading</h2>
```

It is also possible to wrap the number inside a span and place it inside the heading. This makes the number visible to search engines. The CSS will remain the same except that you do not need the content property.

---

Just remembered that you can use [CSS2 counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters) if you simply want to number your headings:

```css
.use-counter {
  counter-reset: foo 0;
}
.count-this:before {
  counter-increment: foo 1;
  content: counter(foo) ".";
  display: inline-block;
  /* customize below */
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  width: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #F77621;
}
```

```html
<section class="use-counter">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  <h2 class="count-this">Fusce sed nunc eget sem euismod</h2>
  <h2 class="count-this">In vel libero in nibh finibus finibus</h2>
  <h2 class="count-this">Nam eleifend nulla ut placerat interdum</h2>
</section>
<section class="use-counter">
  <h1>Aenean ac urna id sapien</h1>
  <h2 class="count-this">Nulla molestie nunc non ultrices</h2>
  <h2 class="count-this">Nam eleifend nulla ut placerat interdum</h2>
  <h2 class="count-this">Curabitur eget sapien tempor arcu</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a great idea too, I kinda thought of it briefly but somewhere in the process I totally forgot about this!  I like this a lot though...will have to check and see how well this works across browsers and platforms and see if it;s viable for the masses yet.  Thanks for sharing

Comment: This is exactly what CSS counters are for.

Answer (score 3):

Put the `span` inside the `h2` and you can edit it however you want using jQuery or pure JS.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqamnyzc/)

HTML: `<h2><span class="number">2</span>How to Get Detailed PPC Keyword Data</h2>`

CSS:

```
h2 span.number {
    color:white;
    background:orange;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:4px 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* or whatever you want to do with your badge */
}
```

In case you are wondering: this is 100% valid, `span` is an inline element and can be put anywhere you want and it won't disturb your regular text flow.

Comment: I was afraid that the span inside the H@ might not be great for SEO purposes, any ideas on that?

Comment: As far as I know that doesn't influence SEO at all, see this discussion about that: http://forums.seochat.com/web-design-coding-programming-11/nested-span-inside-h1-2-tags-good-bad-search-engine-optimization-296847.html

Comment: @jasondavis Where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 2):

Just make both the number and the h2 inline-block elements.

```css
    .number-circles .num {
        content: "2";
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0.6em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -ms-border-radius: 50%;
        -o-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 1.6em;
        height: 1.6em;
        font-weight: 900;
        line-height: 1.6;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1em;
        background: #F77621;
    }

    .number-circles h2 {
         display: inline-block; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="number-circles">
  <span class="num">2</span>
  <h2>How to Get Detailed PPC Keyword Data</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: @jasondavis - This solution didn't work for me when I tested it. Also, does this solution use the `content: "2";` which you said you didn't want?

Comment: This still works the same as the problem stated in the question.

Comment: the original question/problem has been edited to adapt the proposed change offered here

Comment: one possible option is to make both the span and h2 block elements and let them float, while giving the h2 element a fixed maximal width. that way won't cause the elements to shift.

if you don't want to use a fixed width for the h2 elements, try @salman_a 's solution, if HTML5 is an option.