# CSS/HTML - Horizontal line of circled numbers

Tags: html, css, geometry

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle)

I'm trying to take a string of numbers and place circles around them. How do I get them to display in one long horizontal line as opposed to one circle per line?

07, 06, 08, 02, 86, 05, 01, 03, 88, 87, 04

```
<div class="numberCircle">07</div>, <div class="numberCircle">06</div>, <div   class="numberCircle">08</div>, <div class="numberCircle">02</div>, <div class="numberCircle">86</div>, <div class="numberCircle">05</div>, <div class="numberCircle">01</div>, <div class="numberCircle">03</div>, <div class="numberCircle">88</div>, <div class="numberCircle">87</div>, <div class="numberCircle">04</div>, <div class="numberCircle">07</div>, <div class="numberCircle">06</div>,<label><b><del>08</b></del>, <b><del>02</b></del>, <b><del>05</b></del>, <b><del>01</b></del>, <b><del>87</b></del>, <b><del>04</b></del>, </label><br>
```

Basically I'm trying to replicate
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FC0Q.jpg).

Comment: Can't you just write ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩? ;)

Comment: @MrLister Though the circle is probably only decorative, not meaningful. :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you can give circles to your number easily through **CSS3**  **border-radius** property.

And this will work in IE if you will properly use the PIE.htc in your code for IE support border-radius. **{PIE stands for Progressive Internet Explorer. It is an IE attached behavior which, when applied to an element, allows IE to recognize and display a number of CSS3 properties.}**

I have made code in **ordered list** with the use of [**CSS3 counter-increment**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/counter-increment) property for getting the results as per your demo image.

**See the demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/UjfBZ/10/

Comment: IE supports border-radius and all those counter properties without any proprietary .htc JavaScript. Also the numbers are content, they aren't style, you shouldn't be using CSS for them at all (for the circular border is appropriate) - empty li's is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS float:

```
div.numberCircle {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use `div` elements, which are block (what you are asking to not have).  If the numbers have no meaning (unlikely), you could use `span` elements (with `display: inline-block;` in this case), which are inline (basically what you're asking for).  `float: left;` is also an option, but CSS (style) decisions should come after HTML (meaning) ones.  More likely you should be using `li` elements inside an ordered list (`ol`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.numberCircle {
    float: left;
    clear:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can define your div.numberCircle `display inline-block` properties as like this

```
div.numberCircle {
display:inline-block;
   zoom:1; // for ie
*display:inline;  // for ie
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/QYSvB/