# Circle around :before element

Tags: geometry, css

Hello I'm trying to figure out the same question that what was asked in this thread [How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-use-css-to-surround-a-number-with-a-circle)

However - everytime I do it, the shape becomes oval, regardless if I add width/height or not...

I created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dDuFv/

```
<ul class="numberCircle">
    <li>testing</li>
    <li>testing</li>
    <li>testing</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.numberCircle { list-style-type:none; font-size:18px; }
.numberCircle li { margin:20px;}
.numberCircle li:before {
    border-radius:100%;
    counter-increment: section;
    content:counter(section);
    background: #f1562c;
    color:#fff;
    padding:2px;
    border:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but it's just not working!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `display:inline-block;` to the pseudo class. It should work.

Write:

```
.numberCircle li:before {
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dDuFv/1/)

Comment: Awesome answer, but why is this needed to make it function properly?  Just curious

Comment: Thanks, because by default, pseudo element is inline, properties suct as height,width,margin etc etc. are not applicable on `inline` elements.

Comment: Hmm, so now its hard to get the text centered in the circle, any thoughts? thanks for the previous answer!

Comment: @Matt welcome :) isn't the text centered? you can write `text-align:center`

Comment: Nevermind it works, for some reason copying your jsfiddle worked even though I had the same code..I believe..