# Make number of ol to fit in icon

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a list of Football players. Therefore I have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/1/). However, I would like the number of the `ol` to be placed inside an icon. The problem is that two digit numbers overflow that icon. How to fix this?

My CSS is:

```
ol {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol.ui-listview>li>.ui-btn:first-child:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-li-static:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>label:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>.ui-controlgroup-label:before{
    content: counter(listnumbering) !important;
}

#slots {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: There are many options in this thread and I think a few suit you need of fitting in text with more than 1 digit. Have a look if you haven't done already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-use-css-to-surround-a-number-with-a-circle

Comment: @Harry I had seen that and the top answer was good. However, it interferes with jQuery mobile and things fall apart!

Comment: Oh ok. I'll leave the comment there just so that somebody else doesn't link it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css

```
ol {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol.ui-listview>li>.ui-btn:first-child:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-li-static:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>label:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>.ui-controlgroup-label:before{
    content: counter(listnumbering) !important;
    text-align:center;
}

#slots {
    text-align: center;
}

ol > li > a{padding-left:9px !important;}
```