# Circle around inline number

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a circle border around a number like so: 
[image]

But so far all my attempts have resulted in an oval:

[image]

[Codepen to see it live](https://codepen.io/LatteDrift/pen/OOvgyd)
SCSS code so far

```
$browser-context: 16;

@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
    @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #e5dde1;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.header-nav {
    background-color: #ff4c61;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.category-nav ul {
  background-color: #212d5b;
  color: #ff4c61;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.category-nav a {
  font-size: em(34);  
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-nav .circled {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: em(12);
      height: em(12);
      padding: em(4);
      border: em(1) solid #ff4c61;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="header-nav">
  <h1> APP</h1>
</header>
<nav class="category-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C <span class="circled">3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I been experimenting different solutions so far and I think the problem comes mostly from the fact that container of the number is an inline element (span). Whenever I switch the class `.circled` to a div instead or set the display to block, I get a perfect circle but then the number is pushed out and it breaks the flex layout. I wonder if there's any way to get the circle to work with a span?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-use-css-to-surround-a-number-with-a-circle)

Comment: @ochi No because that answer deals only works with blocked elements, here I was trying to make a circle with an inline element that wouldn't break the flex layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `.circled` class you need to add the following styles:

```
.category-nav .circled {
    ...
    line-height: em(12); /* needs to match the height */
    display: inline-block; /* needs to not be an inline element */
    text-align: center; /* center the character*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm! Was unaware that the line-height had to match and forgot about inline-block

Answer (score 1):

You could make it an inline-block. Adding this to your example worked for me:

```
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: em(12);
  text-align: center;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4861306/7427111) answer for more information

```css
$browser-context: 16;
@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #e5dde1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header-nav {
  background-color: #ff4c61;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.category-nav ul {
  background-color: #212d5b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.category-nav a {
  color: #ff4c61;
  font-size: em(34);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-nav .circled {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: em(12);
  height: em(12);
  padding: em(4);
  border: em(1) solid #ff4c61;
}

.numberCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: auto;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-nav">
  <h1> APP</h1>
</header>
<nav class="category-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C <div class="numberCircle">3</div></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```