# Unable to widen CSS circle/oval around number

Tags: html, css, asp.net

**Goal**: Draw green circle around a number

I want it to look like this:

[image]

**Problem**: It actually looks like this(It seems to take the shape of the number):

[image]

**CSS**:

```
.oval {
    background-color: #92D050;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I've tried adjusting the width, but the width has no effect, if I take it out it looks exactly the same.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" CssClass="professoricon"/>
<sup><asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Font-Size="20px" CssClass="oval"/></sup>
```

I used the  to give the appearance that the number was slightly higher than the image.

Ive looked at other SO posts such as [Circle around inline number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419567/circle-around-inline-number) as well as articles such as https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_circles.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width and height will not work in your case unless you set the display property of the label.

Try adding padding to the element instead.

```css
.oval {
    background-color: #92D050;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

```html
Test<sup><label class="oval">2</label></sup>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is that an `asp:Label` generates a `<span>` element in HTML if there is no `AssociatedControlID` property. With that property it does generate a `<label>` element. This is important because a span element needs `display: inline-block;` in css, while a label does not.

```
<style>
    .oval {
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #92D050;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

If you want a bigger circle, but the same font size, fool around with the size and line-height

```
width: 34px;
height: 34px;
line-height: 30px;
```